# Without compromising on neither/either?

Tags: neither-nor

What's the right way to say it?

```
Without compromising on either efficiency nor accuracy,...
```

or

```
Without compromising on neither efficiency nor accuracy,...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard English (of whichever part of the English speaking world), explicitly negative words and phrases such as *no*, *none*,*never*, *nowhere*,  *neither*, and *nor* cannot be used within the scope of another negative (such as *not* or *without*), but only when they themselves are the primary carrier of negative meaning. (In many non-standard Englishes, this is not true).

So *without compromising on either efficiency **or** accuracy,...*

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood what your statement implies, rightly, 
you should write it as-
Without compromising on *either* efficiency **or** accuracy.
Compromising *neither* on efficiency *nor* accuracy.

Comment: To give a general rule that you can use going forward, you always pair **either** with **or**, and **neither** with **nor**. The best way to remember is that one of the pairs uses words starting with the same letter, and the other set both start with vowels.